# Any suggestions on how I can integrate cloud storage with my native Java application in Windows

Tags: java, cloud

I am developing a hospital information system which does a lot of stuff such as capturing patient and medical practitioner's details. The system is supposed to generate daily reports which should be stored safely. What I want the system to do is to store those generated reports in say dropbox without having to open the browser and entering url (usual way) but using a few clicks within the app so that backup can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox offers a Java API for core features, you can access Dropbox file content with it: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

If the user does not need to retrieve the files directly you can also use the datastore API which allows you to store your application Data: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/http

For both APIs you need to create an application key. The user has to visit the dropbox site once, afterwards you can work in the background. A simpler alternative would be a file export, the user could choose the sync directory of any cloud service he desires.

Comment: OK...thanks, very nice suggestion. Exporting the file will come as standard but I still think uploading it will be a nice idea...let me look into Dropbox's Java API. Thankyou!